# Is there a standard notation for a set which contains all the coordinates that are a part of a circle with a given radius?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, analytic-geometry

Let's say that we have a circle with a radius of $R$ units with it's centre coinciding with the origin of the *Cartesian Plane*.

It's equation will be : $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$

Now, does there exist a standard notation of a set that contains the coordinates of all the points that lie on the circle ($C_R$, for example)? If I ever use such a set in any statement, do I consider it to be predefined or define it whilst writing the statement? I have stated an example of a situation where I might use the statement below.
$$\text{If } x \in \Bbb R \text{, } (\cos x, \sin x) \in C_1$$
If I need to define $C_R$, I will define it as follows :
$$C_R = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = R^2 \}$$
and hence, I would define $C_1$ as follows :
$$C_1 = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1^2 = 1 \}$$
I know that this seems pretty obvious but I'm asking this question as I've not seen this notation being used anywhere yet.

Also, $n(C_R) = \infty$, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually need to define the circle? Would "if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|cos(x),sin(x)|=1$" not be simpler?

Comment: What are the $||$? I've only seen them used in the *modulus funtion*

Comment: It's the norm (more precise: the Euclidean norm). Basically the length of a vector, defined as $|(x,y)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. One can leave the normal brackets away,  as I did, to avoid clutter.. you can also write $\|(x,y)\|_2$ to make it even more obvious...

Comment: That would be simpler, agreed. But, is the method that I suggest mathematically correct?

Comment: I would only define $C_R$, and not $C_1$ (except if R is always 1). You should also define it somewhere. Just be nice to people, if you don't know by heard a notation,  they won't neither. But everything looks ok. And,  yes, $C_R$ doesn't have finite order, if this is implied with your $n(C_R)$ notation (I wouldn't write it like you, but what you mean is correct).

Comment: Thank You @Engineertryingmath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question you asked:

> Now, does there exist a standard notation of a set that contains the coordinates of all the points that lie on the circle ($_$, for example)?

The answer is "yes," and the standard notation is $[-R, R]$, because that set of real numbers contains all coordinates of all points that lie on that circle.

The question I think you meant to ask was "Is there a standard notation of the set of all points whose coordinates satisfy the equation $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$?"

The answer there is "not that I know of." But as other have said, you can say: "Let $C_R$ denote the set of points of the circle of radius $R$" or, more simply, "Let $C_R$ be the circle of radius $R$", because a circle *is* a set of points.

For $R = 1$, there is a very widely accepted notation, namely $S^1$ (the "one dimensional sphere"). You might argue that because it lives in the plane, it's *two*-dimensional, but that ship has sailed: $S^1$ means exactly the set of points whose distance from the origin in the plane is $1$. I've *occasionally* seen people write $3S^1$ to mean "the circle of radius 3", or even $rS^1$ to indicate the circle of radius $r$, but it's uncommon and looks ugly to me, and I cannot recommend it.

Short summary: use a short sentence to define the set $C_R$, and move on.

Comment: The $S^1$ and $3S^1$ notations are clean and well established (it's like writing $2\mathbb{Z}$ for the even numbers). The problem is that this notation will be likely confusing for the audience of @Rajdeep. It's like teaching my son how to count by starting with group theory...

Comment: I disagree about "well established" (but what the hell -- I've only been messing with topology for about 50 years, so maybe I haven't been around enough) and "clean" is in the eye of the beholder. The notation suffers especially when the multiplier is some capital letter like "P", so that you write $PS^2$, which looks suspiciously as if it was meant to be the projectivization of something. Still...to each their own.